# How do you allow users to create own menus?

Tags: routes, users

The idea is that a user should be able to create a menu to structure his uploaded content. How would you go about making this possible without giving the user access to edit other users menus?

Cheers,

Comment: As far as I know there is no out of the box solution for that, it would have to be custom coded. Someone else may know better though.

Comment: There is a Drupal 6 module [Bookmarks](https://www.drupal.org/project/bookmarks) for that from which you may draw inspiration. I see that they plan to integrate it into Advanced Menu.

Comment: Can't u use the core shortcut module somehow? That works on a per user base and allows adding and removing pages to your list.

Answer (score 1):

**[Menu Admin Per Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_admin_per_menu) Module** comes to solve this purpose!!

> The Drupal 7 Menu Admin Per Menu module is a simple module that allows
>   you to grant permissions for users to administer specific Drupal menus
>   based on their role.
>
> This module for instance would allow you to allow one role to modify
>   the Main menu, while not allowing the role to modify a separate menu
>   on your Drupal 7 website.

Watch this Screencast to learn about it : [How to allow a specific role to administer the user menu on a Drupal site without giving them access to modify the Main menu](http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal/drupal-7-menu-admin-menu)

Comment: But this is for the global menus? OP wants a per-user menu.